# Vue.js Not a valid date

Tags: date, vue.js, sharepoint

I have several .vue classes in which I use dates.

The problem I'm having is that when I upload the code on my SharePoint page while using the Chrome debugging tool I get a lot of date errors, such as

`Not a valid date: "2019-09-19T01:00:00Z"`
(see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot]

On the internet I've only found this on github:

https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/master/docs/unicodeTokens.md

So I tried to only have `MM` as upper-case letter, but the error still appeared.

I don't have much experience in Vue.js, so I don't know what exactly I could try to change.

In my `data:function()` I got the following part

```
data: function() {
return {
  baseImageUrl: this.$store.state.baseImageUrl,
  histories: [],

  columns: [
    {
      label: "Created On",
      field: "createdAt",
      type: "date",
      dateInputFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
      dateOutputFormat: "DD.MM.YYYY",
      thClass: "text-left",
      tdClass: "text-center",
      width: '151px',
      filterOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        placeholder: "Date",
       // filterFn: this.myColumnFilter
      }
    },
```

In my `methods` I got

```
HistorysData: function(data) {
  var data = data.d.results;
  this.histories = [];
  var $this = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var Created = this.getJSONDateAsString(data[i].Created, "dd.MM.yyyy");

    $this.rows.push({
      createdAt: data[i].date,
      action: data[i].act,
      details: data[i].details,
      correspondingListID: data[i].CorrespondingListID
    });
  }  
},
```

The `getJSONDateAsString` is defined as

```
getJSONDateAsString: function(jsdatevalue, returnFormat) {
  if ((jsdatevalue == "") | (jsdatevalue == null)) {
    return "";
  }
  return new Date(jsdatevalue).toString(returnFormat);
}
```

Comment: Is `this.getJSONDateAsString` defined? What does it do? The error occurs, because you are using a String as a date.

Comment: Yes it is defined, I edited the post

Comment: Where does this error occur? I don't think that you posted that part here. What is on line 76 (and around) of the file which throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a filter to the date and return a standard date format for output. The Format function comes from [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format), but you can use anything that will format it to MM/DD/YYYY. There are other accepted [ISO formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) but this is the most reliable I have used so far.

```
    DateFilter(dateString: string) {
        if (dateString) {
            return format(dateString, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    },
```

If you need time as well

```
        DateTimeFilter(dateString: string) {
            if (dateString) {
                return format(dateString, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm');
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But where exactly do I have to put the filter in the code?

Comment: @RamanujanTaylor you can create an actual filter in Vue, or just create a method to assist in filtering and return a computed property. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html